# Recursive code running slow on UNix box but fast on windows

Tags: java, unix, recursion

I have a java code which is combination of while loop and recursion. Issue we are facing is that call to below method takes time almost 8 times more on a unix box [HP ProLiant BL460c G7] than a windows box [Intel Xeon CPU E5-1650, 64 bit Windows 7]. Any ideas on how to improve execution time in Unix box.
We are using JDK 1.6_43 [64 bit]

```
protected Date abc(int n, Date date) 
{
    long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (n > 0) 
    {
          while (n > 0)
          {
                --n;
                date = getNextExchangeDateUnadjusted(date);
          }

          return date;
    }
    else 
    {

          Date nextExchangeDate = getNextExchangeDateUnadjusted(date);

          Date previousExchangeDate = getNextExchangeDateUnadjusted(date);

          while (!abc( -n + 1, previousExchangeDate).equals(nextExchangeDate)) 
          {

                date = date.addDays( -14);

                previousExchangeDate = getNextExchangeDateUnadjusted(date);

          }

          return previousExchangeDate;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Following is the code for `getNextExchangeDateUnadjusted` method called above

```
public Date getNextExchangeDateUnadjusted(Date date) {
    // Third Wednesday of each month
    Date thirdWednesdayInMonth = date.getThirdWednesdayInMonth();
    if (thirdWednesdayInMonth.after(date)) {     
      return thirdWednesdayInMonth;
    }
    return date.addMonths(1).getThirdWednesdayInMonth();
  }
}
```

Also want to add that code spends max time in this portion:

```
      while (!abc( -n + 1, previousExchangeDate).equals(nextExchangeDate)) 
      {

            date = date.addDays( -14);

            previousExchangeDate = getNextExchangeDateUnadjusted(date);

      }
```

EDIT2:

We took multiple heap dumps on Unix box as the process progressed and found that 'Retained Heap' started growing from about 1mb goes up to 4.5 mb so stack size is growing substantially. Not sure if that will lead to slow performance. We will now be taking heap dumps in Windows and will also try to change stack size with XSS.

Comment: Post also the code of getNextExchangeDateUnadjusted

Comment: seems to be a problem with the handling of date objects. maybe it's possible to do all calculations with `long` until the very end?

Comment: Are you running with the same JVM settings on both machines? Have you tried playing with the `-Xss` parameter?

Comment: @assylias: We are going to try that on Unix box today. But We are currently not setting it on either unix or windows.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO: I will post the code shortly

Comment: What is the Date type you are using ? (date.getThirdWednesdayInMonth() ?)

Comment: @Thierry: We have our own date class but basically it provides some utilities and internally uses java.util.Date only

Comment: Are you sure it is not its equals method or addDays that are slow ? a jvisualvm comparison of the windows box vs the unix box would show you what is taking so much more time on the unix box.

Comment: @Thierry: Yes, i will be sharing visual vm details as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi pronged approach was adopted in order to resolve this issue:

1. We ruled out any IO or remote calls causing unnecessary delay.
2. Heap dumps were taken via Visual VM to see any unusual behaviour within the process and comparison was done between Unix and windows. All we could trace here was that main thread was taking up 4.5mb of stack space but it was same in both Unix and windows.
3. Only option left now was to see if there were any gaps in JVM's on unix and windows and if there were any optimization gaps between the 2.

Issue was spotted in 3 part, following was the gap when we ran the command `java -version`

- **On Windows**

  java version "1.6.0_43"

  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)

  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)
- **On Unix**

  java version "1.6.0_43"

  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)

  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, interpreted mode)

You can see the clear difference in JVM hotspot mode between unix and windows. On further investigations we found that JVM running in `Interpreted` doesn't optimize the code [This article has details on it: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/useful-jvm-flags-part-1-jvm-types-and-compiler-modes/ ].
So we started our process on Unix box with flag `-Xmixed` which forced JVM to work in mixed mode. This resolved our issue and Unix and Windows performance became same.

EDIT:

JVM was being pushed to interpreted mode due to this parameter in unix box: `-Djava.compiler=NONE`

Comment: But then someone must have forced the `interpreted mode` as the `mixed mode` is choosen as default. Listing the `-X` options shows `-Xmixed  mixed mode execution (default)`.

Comment: Yes thats correct, it was being caused by this parameter : -Djava.compiler=NONE which is part of legacy code. This was pushing jvm to interpreter mode. I will update the answer with this.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you first take pen and paper to fix the logic in your code.

I did following for you

```
assume abc is initially called as abc(1, "date < 3th Wednesday")
it will return "3th Wednesday in the same month"

assume abc is initially called as abc(0, "date < 3th Wednesday")
1. while loop iteration
abc(1, 3th Wednesday in the same month)
  - return 3th Wednesday of month+1
- as this is not equal with the "3th Wednesday in the same month"
   (nextExchangeDate) you compute "date - 14 day"
2. while loop iteration abc will be called as abc(1, "date - 14 day")
which return "3th Wednesday of month-1"
3. while loop iteration abc will be called as abc(1, "3th Wednesday of month-1")
...
```

There I stopped. It looks more like trial and error then computation. I would fix that first before looking for performance differences.

Ok here are an example of the computation

with start date "16.11.2015" and n = 1

```
abc(1, 16.11.2015)
16.11.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 18.11.2015
abc date: 18.11.2015
```

with start date "16.11.2015" and n = 0

```
abc(0, 16.11.2015)
16.11.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 18.11.2015
16.11.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 18.11.2015
abc(1, 18.11.2015)
18.11.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 18.11.2015
18.11.2015 + (1) month
18.12.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 16.12.2015
16.11.2015 + (-14) days
02.11.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 18.11.2015
abc(1, 18.11.2015)
18.11.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 18.11.2015
18.11.2015 + (1) month
18.12.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 16.12.2015
02.11.2015 + (-14) days
19.10.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 21.10.2015
abc(1, 21.10.2015)
21.10.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 21.10.2015
21.10.2015 + (1) month
21.11.2015 get 3th Wed ==> 18.11.2015
abc date: 21.10.2015 (the 3th Wed of previous month)
```

I don't believe that there isn't a better way to compute it.

Comment: Code is working fine and issue is performance. Its legacy stuff and changing it is last option for us. Problem is why it works faster in windows?

Comment: @Lokesh For simple date computation there shouldn't be a significat difference.

Comment: We have evidence that there is a difference. Our Process as part of generating data files calls this method and in windows process takes 5 mins while in unix process takes between 30 to 40 min. That is with same code

Comment: @Lokesh And you are sure that the time is lost callind the abc() method? Even the posted code shouldn't take five minutes for the computation. Could you provide an example of `date` and `n` where it takes that long? Is there other code involved in the mentioned abc() method loop?